# Javascript: Clear html input when input loses focus

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input name="input15" type="text" size="50" onblur="var input15 = document.getElementById("input15"); input.value == """/>
```

Anyone know why the input field isn't getting cleared when I click out of the input box?

I'll type the name "Bob" into the input field then when I click on the blank white space outside the field, the field does not get cleared.

Comment: try `onblur="this.value=''"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<input name="input15" type="text" size="50" onblur="this.value=''"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pUFpD/)

Answer (score 0):

the name of your var is input15, and then after the semi colon you use input.value rather than input15.value?  Also you have the == instead of assignment...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function clearText(){
       document.getElementById("input15").value = "";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input15" type="text" size="50" onblur="clearText()" /> 
  </body>
</html>
```